# Raster layer with unique vector for each raster cell

Tags: raster

I am working on a WebGIS tool that interprets local geology. From more than 70 asc-files, I would like to create one raster layer that contains in each raster cell the local geology, e.g. as a 2 x n vector with a code for the present formations and their thickness.

First of all, is this a good idea or is it better to query all layers in the WebGIS tool for the specific location?

I tried already to create a raster file, where each cell value was linked to a vector in a sort of attribute table. However, I was unable to save this table in Python, unless as a txt-file, and directly link it to the raster file.

Is there a specific raster type that does this?

Comment: For your information, I did it with a shapefile in which each raster cell is represented as a polygon. It is a large file but it works very well in the online application.